# Pandas - mean of matches minus mean of non-matches within each group

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have this dataframe named main_df

```
    tf      organs
1   ALX3    brain,heart
2   ARID5A  kidney
```

And using this reference dataframe named ref_df,

```
    tf      organ   expression
1   ALX3    brain   2
2   ALX3    heart   5
3   ALX3    kidney  4
4   ARID5A  brain   3
5   ARID5A  heart   6
6   ARID5A  kidney  1
```

I want to add a column to main_df named delta where it takes the mean of the corresponding values in ref_df and subtracts the mean of the remaining values for that tf. So in row 1, it would be

mean([2,5])-mean([4]) = -0.5

and in row 2, it would be

mean([1])-mean([3,6]) = -3.5

making main_df now looking like this:

```
    tf      organs      delta
1   ALX3    brain,heart -0.5
2   ARID5A  kidney      -3.5
```

I've been thinking about this for a while, but I'm stuck. Would I need to use the pandas function isin() or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Step 1***
*Turn `ref_df` into something easier to use in the function I'll define*

```
rdf = ref_df.set_index(['tf', 'organ']).expression.unstack()
rdf

organ   brain  heart  kidney
tf                          
ALX3        2      5       4
ARID5A      3      6       1
```

***Step 2***
*Use `split` to generate list of organs for positive mean.  Use `difference` to generate list of organs for negative mean.*

```
def delta(row):
    p = row.organs.split(',')
    n = rdf.columns.difference(p)
    return rdf.loc[row.tf, p].mean() - rdf.loc[row.tf, n].mean()
```

***Step 3***
*`apply` + `assign` to produce new dataframe with new column*

```
main_df.assign(detla=main_df.apply(delta, 1))

       tf       organs  detla
1    ALX3  brain,heart   -0.5
2  ARID5A       kidney   -3.5
```